# How do I install an originally not installed Xampp service

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I originally installed Xampp I didn't install MySQL as I didn't need it. I do now, how can I install it without uninstalling Xampp??

Comment: You should be able to just install MySQL by itself and load the database manually.

Comment: I'd like to have it available by the Xampp Control Panel

Comment: Backup your Xampp configuration.  You should be able to use the installer to add this feature.

Comment: That's what I did, I were just hoping for something easier that I missed.

Comment: That **IS** the easy way.